# PCI Soundcard to function

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, soundcard

I've installed a PCI Soundcard, and it seems like Ubuntu is recognizing it, I'm able to see it in `alsamixer` but when I go into the Ubuntu sound settings I can't get any sound. I've tried a few tutorials showing how to manually add drivers, but nothing I've tried seems to help and they are all pretty vague. I'm not an Ubuntu power user by any stretch of the imagination. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, on a Dell optiplex 745, and the card is an ICEncemble ICE 1724. See image below for `alsamixer` settings.

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25539/discussion-on-question-by-user2340702-pci-soundcard-to-function).

Comment: The card is an  ICEncemble ICE 1724

Comment: Please post a PulseAudio log https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PulseAudio/Log

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Af7CcG4a Here is the pulseaudio log

Comment: Thank you for the log. I see some related messages and that PulseAudio gives up on configuring this card, unfortunately I cannot give you any further advice. Other members from the PulseAudio list or the developers may be able to help you: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Community/